# Is it possible to replace string with hash / symbol (:created_at)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is it possible to write this lines in hash format (:created_at)

```
User.where("created_at > ?", Time.now - 1.month) 
User.where("created_at >= ?", DateTime.parse('2012-10-31')
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic ActiveRecord doesn't support that. However the underlying query generation library (called AREL) does. However plain AREL is rather inconvenient to write which is where [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) comes into play. It extends ActiveRecord and provides an extended Ruby DSL for specifying conditions.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i was expecting a hack/native(rails) solution rather going for gem (Squeel gem, etc...). Your answer was helpful too. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the [Squeel Gem](https://github.com/ernie/squeel)

You will be able to write code like `Article.where{created_at >= 2.weeks.ago}` as shown in the documentation.

It's not exactly a hash format, but it's really more elegant than your examples.

Comment: i was expecting a hack/native(rails) solution rather going for gem. Your answer was helpful too. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to get away from meta_where/squeel since it's not supported anymore. The only viable solution currently that I see, it's to dig into AREL:

```ruby
User.where(User.arel_table[:created_at].gt(1.month.ago))
User.where(User.arel_table[:created_at].gteq(DateTime.parse('2012-10-31'))
```

You can put all your queries/scopes in a separate class from the model and encapsulate a lot of verbosity, look here:

- More info: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-arel-to-compose-sql-queries
- Predicates: https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/predications.rb

You get a lot of benefit with this. All your scopes merging will work beautifully because arel will handle the aliasing for you.

On a personal note, I'm now in the Rails 3.0.20 ghetto because I rely heavily on meta_where that is not compatible with Rails 3.1+. I'm slowly replacing all the meta_where to arel.